# use azure key vault secret into manifest of KubernetesManifest@0 task

Tags: kubernetes, azure-pipelines, azure-aks, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a pipeline job in which I download two secrets using the following task:

```yaml
- task: AzureKeyVault@2
  displayName: 'Download secret 1'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'my-subscription'
    KeyVaultName: 'my-key-vault'
    SecretsFilter: 'secret-1'
    RunAsPreJob: true
    OutputVariable: secret-1
            
- task: AzureKeyVault@2
  displayName: 'Download secret 2'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'my-subscription'
    KeyVaultName: 'my-key-vault'
    SecretsFilter: 'secret-2'
    RunAsPreJob: true
    OutputVariable: secret-2
```

Now, I want to use these two secrets values inside the manifest that i provide to this task (I tried using `secretArguments`):

```yaml
- task: KubernetesManifest@0
  displayName: 'Deploy Slim Buster OAuth2 Proxy for Authentication'
  inputs:
    action: 'deploy'
    kubernetesServiceConnection: 'my-kube-connection'
    namespace: 'my-namespace'
    manifests: 'path/to/manifest.yaml'
    containers: 'quay.io/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy:v7.3.0'
    secretArguments: --from-literal=secret-1=$(secret-1) --from-literal=secret-2=$(secret-2)
```

and inside the manifest file i try using these two secrets as the followingL

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
.
.
.
spec:
  containers:
    env:
     - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_SECRET
       value: $(secret-1)
     - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_COOKIE_SECRET
       value: $(secret-2)
```

but the deployment of the kubernetes manifest task fails; after being stuck for dozens of minutes...

can you help me fix it? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using an extra task from bash that calls the command envsubst so it creates a new file with the changes

`cat manifest.yaml | envsubst > "manifest.final.yaml"`

So the final version will look like this

```
......
- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    environment: 'staging'
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: Bash@3
            displayName: Build k8s files
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                cd $(Pipeline.Workspace); \
                cat manifest.yaml | envsubst > "manifest.final.yaml"
            env:
    # This are my envs to replace
              REPLICAS_NUM: 1
              CONTAINER_PORT: 8000
              HEALTHZ_PATH: '/'
              IMAGE_NAME: '$(containerRegistry)/$(imageRepository):$(tag)'
              VERSION: 'build_$(tag)'

          - task: KubernetesManifest@0
            displayName: Deploy to Kubernetes cluster
            inputs:
              action: deploy
              manifests: |
                $(Pipeline.Workspace)/manifest.final.yaml
              imagePullSecrets: |
                $(imagePullSecret)
              containers: |
                $(containerRegistry)/$(imageRepository):$(tag)
.....
```

Maybe it's not the best solution but it works
:D